# How to prevent PM2 to change the current directory?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Im using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to handle my nodejs micro services and [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) to handle the views:

```
var hbs = exphbs.create({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  helpers: {
    ifeq: function(a, b, options) {
      if (a === b) {
        return options.fn(this);
      }
      return options.inverse(this);
    },
    toJSON : function(object) {
      return JSON.stringify(object);
    }
  }
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Lunching the app directly (node app.js) works great. But if I lunch it using PM2 (pm2 start app.js) i get:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "/root/views"

When lunching pm2 the current working directory change to /root/ and since my app in not there I got an error from handlebars trying to open the views directory (which is in the app directory).

Is there a way to fix this by telling pm2 the current working directory or by telling the express-handlebars library the complete directory instead of using a relative one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Koa and SWIG for templates - but I needed to include the path to the views in the app setup:

```
app.use(koaRender('./server/server-side-views', {
        map: { html: 'swig' },
        cache: false
}));
```

I suspect it is more of the same for you.  I think in express your code should be something along the line of:

```
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/yourViewDirectory');
```

Comment: This seems to fix the problem, but now im getting: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/views/layouts/main.handlebars'

I tried app.set('layouts', __dirname + '/views/layouts'); but nothing, maybe the parameter is not layouts?

Comment: I can't really help you with your specifics.  Try adding some console logs in there to see what paths are being set and see if they match what you expect